# What is the most common word in EmEditor

Tags: emeditor

I got like 30mlion words in Emeditor format looks like:

```
Money
Love
Money
France
Telephone
Fork
.
.
.
```

I would like to know which word has the most repetitions. its possible to check it?
I dont want do it manualy like bookmarking or find next.

I would like it in this form or in any other:

3200 Money

3190 Love

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **EmEditor**, select **Extract Frequent Strings** on the **Search** menu, accept the default options, and click **OK**.

[image]

The result output of your sample will be like this:

[image: Extract Frequent Strings output]

If you prefer a macro, use this line:

```
document.selection.ExtractFrequent(eeFreqTypeLines, eeFindReplaceCase, 1, 100, "");
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Macro.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Macro.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while a document with a list of words is active.